# Ошибка в строке new Socket

Tags: java, android, сокет, connection

Пытаюсь подключиться к серверу на Python через приложение на Android используя сокеты. Подключение происходит по нажатию кнопки с помощью OnClick. Однако банально не могу ничего сделать, ибо происходит ошибка в строке с формированием сокета в Android Studio. Если в браузере ввести ip:port, то подключается, так что проблема не с доступом.
**Сервер**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('192.168.0.100', 2212))
server.listen(3)

client_socket, address = server.accept()
print("Connect", address)
```

**Клиент**

```
Socket socket = null;
    public void serverTest() {
        Log.d("Server", "SocketConnect");
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 2212); //На эту строку ошибка в компиляторе
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все было просто. В Android необходимо производить подключение в отдельном потоке, а не в основном. Нашел ответ только благодаря тому, что написал этот вопрос. При использовании поиска ранее - ответ не смог найти.